# MySQL GROUP BY Ver 8 vs Ver 5.X

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Good day,

I am fairly new to MySQL and I have been studying it. I have been following a very old tutorial that uses ver 5.X. I am using ver 8.0.29 on my VM. Using the sample world database I am having issues grouping by Continent using the query below.

```
SELECT Continent, Region, SUM(Popuilation) AS TotalPop FROM country GROUP BY Contient, Region;

+---------------+---------------------------+------------+
| Continent     | Region                    | TotalPop   |
+---------------+---------------------------+------------+
| North America | Caribbean                 |   38140000 |
| Asia          | Southern and Central Asia | 1490776000 |
| Africa        | Central Africa            |   95652000 |
| Europe        | Southern Europe           |  144674200 |
| Asia          | Middle East               |  188380700 |
| South America | South America             |  345780000 |
| Oceania       | Polynesia                 |     633050 |
| Antarctica    | Antarctica                |          0 |
| Oceania       | Australia and New Zealand |   22753100 |
| Europe        | Western Europe            |  183247600 |
| Africa        | Eastern Africa            |  246999000 |
| Africa        | Western Africa            |  221672000 |
| Europe        | Eastern Europe            |  307026000 |
| North America | Central America           |  135221000 |
| North America | North America             |  309632000 |
| Asia          | Southeast Asia            |  518541000 |
| Africa        | Southern Africa           |   46886000 |
| Asia          | Eastern Asia              | 1507328000 |
| Europe        | Nordic Countries          |   24166400 |
| Africa        | Northern Africa           |  173266000 |
| Europe        | Baltic Countries          |    7561900 |
| Oceania       | Melanesia                 |    6472000 |
| Oceania       | Micronesia                |     543000 |
| Europe        | British Islands           |   63398500 |
| Oceania       | Micronesia/Caribbean      |          0 |
+---------------+---------------------------+------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What have I been doing wrong? The VTC Tutorial shows continent is being grouped fine.

I truly apologize for my noobness on this topic in advance...

Comment: You are grouping by continent and region but not ordering

Comment: You misspelled `Contient` in the `GROUP BY`, but I'm guessing that's not it

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the typos, got issues sharing clipboards from Oracle VM.  Also thank you for suggesting using order by. I did check on some old questions for MySQL and came across this blog. So they somehow removed sorting for Group By at some point, https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/ So lesson learned, keep up to date with the Tutorials and version changes. Stay awesome people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, except for the typo in the `Contient`. However, if you want your result set to be ordered in terms of the Continents, you have to add a order by clause in the query.

```
SELECT Continent, Region, SUM(Population) as TotalPop
FROM country
GROUP BY Continent, Region
ORDER BY Continent, Region;
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, this is the reason why. https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/